# Activities, (and especially one's current role, school, etc.) should probably be ranked by END date, not start date

Tags: bug, developer-story

My current role is ongoing, but it shows up [after blog posts I've written since I joined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/347414).

I'd guess it's either because:

- the ordering always uses start date for sorting, OR
- It uses end date, but since "current" roles have none, it goes by the start

But that feels off - my current job is my most recent thing; it's still happening right now.

By way of example, here are three positions:

[image]

The obviously correct ordering from top to bottom is Autodesk (my current position, with no end date), 500px (where I worked 8 months ago) followed by Mosaic. The actual rendering is 500px, Autodesk, Mosaic.

**Note**: The order is fixed if I change my start date at Autodesk to 2015/06 instead of 2015/05. The error appears to occur when the start date for the current position and the end date for the previous position are the same (both are 2015/05 in this case).

Comment: Jealous that I see the links but cannot get to the developer stories :(.